# Google cloud build : .availableSecrets: unused

Tags: google-cloud-platform, continuous-integration, google-cloud-build, google-secret-manager

I am trying to run a step using cloud build and using secret manager but I get an error.

My cloudbuild.yaml is:

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/myproject/image:latest'
  args:
  - '-arg1=blablabla'
  - '-mysysttem.login=$$LOGIN'
  - '-arg3=blablabla'
  - '-arg4=blabla'
  secretEnv: ['LOGIN'] 
availableSecrets:
  secretManager:
  - versionName: projects/myproject/secrets/mysecret/versions/latest
    env: 'LOGIN'
```

and when executing:
`gcloud builds submit --config cloudbuild.yaml`

I get the following error

`ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) interpreting cloudbuild.yaml as build config: .availableSecrets: unused`

Couldnt find anything related to it when searching for this error

Answer (score 1):

So after I investigating more I figured I had an old gcloud cli version installed on my computer.
The command to run the update is:

`gcloud components update`

This fixed my error